# ios different image sizes for UIActivity subclass

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

iOS documentation describes that UIActivity subclass should return image for 'activityImage' with different sizes for iPhone, iPad and iOS 6, iOS 7.

> For iPhone and iPod touch, images on iOS 7 should be 60 by 60 points;
>   on earlier versions of iOS, you should use images no larger than 43 by
>   43 points. For iPad, images on iOS 7 should be 76 by 76 points; on
>   earlier versions of iOS you should use images no larger than 60 by 60
>   points. On a device with Retina display, the number of pixels is
>   doubled in each direction.

What is the correct way to return the image:

- Create if/else block following the device iPHone/iPad and iOS6/iOS7 to return. I think this not the best way.
- Name the images following the naming convention (such as suffix ~iPHone, ~iPad, ....), then we just create the image with one name in coding. The system automatically match the correct image file. I think this is the best way, but I don't know the naming convention.

Which is the way should I use? Thank you!

Comment: I answer your question, Did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is always follow the Apple standard:

For iPad:
 - someIpadImageIcon@2x~ipad
 - someIpadImageIcon~ipad

For iPhone:
 - someIphoneImageIcon@2x
 - someIphoneImageIcon

Hope it helps you